# Perl: Subroutine Output; input into foreach statement

Tags: perl, foreach, subroutine

I have a subrouting that outputs a list of FQDN's, separated by new lines:

```
x1.server.com
s2.sys.com
5a.fdsf.com
```

^^ It's in this format, so there's no pattern other than {variable text}.{variable text}.{variable text}

My question is how would I be able to get THIS output as the input of a foreach statement so that I can iterate through each FQDN?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NB:** You say the sub outputs a list, but I assume what you mean is that it outputs a string. Otherwise, this question is moot.

Just split the output on newline. Assuming the subroutine is called `subname`:

```
for my $fqdn (split /\n/, subname())
```

As Brian Roach notes in the comments, the optimal solution is to make the subroutine return a list instead of a string. However, that may not be a viable solution for you. Either way, if you wish to try it, simply add the `split` at the appropriate place in the subroutine instead. E.g.:

```
sub foo {
    ...
    #return $string;
    return split /\n/, string;
}
```

If you want to get advanced, you may make use of the [`wantarray`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html) function, which detects in which context the subroutine is called:

```
sub foo {
    ...
    return $string unless wantarray;
    return split /\n/, string;
}
```

While this is very cute, it can lead to unwanted behaviour unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: +1 Or ... change the subroutine to actually return an array rather than a string.

Comment: @BrianRoach That would be optimal for this case, but it may be that he cannot alter the subroutine due to it being used elsewhere.

Comment: @TLP - thanks for this, I'll accept your answer.  @Brian Roach: I ended up actually taking your advice.  I added `push @results,$domain` and then `return @results` into their respected parts of the subroutine and then called the `foreach` loop like `foreach $host (get_mirror_list()) {` and it worked beautifully.  I'm not an expert at perl so any expert advice I can get I try to implement that was rather than the easy way, although, it did seem easier to do it this way.  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to preserve trailing blank lines, you'll need `split /^/m, $_, -1` instead of `split /\n/, $_`.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $data = mySubRoutine()
# Data now contains one FQDN per line

foreach (my $line = split(/\n/,$data))
{
     doStuffWith($line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you really mean that your subroutine "outputs" a list - i.e. that it prints the list to STDOUT. Do you have something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub print_list_of_fqdns {
  say "x1.server.com\ns2.sys.com\n5a.fdsf.com";
}

print_list_of_fqdns();
```

If that's the case then you need to be a bit clever and re-open STDOUT onto a variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub print_list_of_fqdns {
  say "x1.server.com\ns2.sys.com\n5a.fdsf.com";
}

sub get_list_of_fqdns {
  # Declare a buffer
  my $string;

  # Open a filehandle that writes to the buffer
  open my $fh, '>', \$string or die $!;

  # Set your new filehandle to the default output filehandle
  # (taking a copy of the original one)
  my $old_fh = select $fh;

  # Call the function. This will now write the list to the
  # variable $string instead of STDOUT
  print_list_of_fqdns();

  # Split $string to get the individual FQDNs
  my @fqdns = split /\n/, $string;

  # Replace the old default output filehandle
  select $old_fh;

  # Return the list of FQDNs
  return @fqdns;
}

say join ' / ', get_list_of_fqdns();
```